# Jquery - Select and Replace CSS class

Tags: jquery

I have a little piece of code like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <form id="frmButtons">
        <div id="datagrid">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="ColVis">
                    <button class="ColVis_Button ColVis_MasterButton ui-button ui-state-default">
                        <span>Change Columns</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My button does not have an ID or name. How do I select and replace the "class" attribute of that button? I am trying this, but it doesn't work.

```
$("div.Colvis button").toggleClass("newButtonClass");
```

Comment: Is that button triggering a post back since it's in a form?

Comment: nope. It just shows or hides a div

Comment: can you provide the css classes for completeness?

Comment: Why? I just need to replace the CSS class "ColVis_Button ColVis_MasterButton ui-button ui-state-default" with a class called "newButtonClass" for the button in my form using JQuery

Comment: @Jake for completeness so that anyone else attempting to perhaps hide a div or button would also benefit from this question as it stands this is just a typo issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to completely change the class of the button:

```
$("div.ColVis > button").prop('class', 'newButtonClass');
```

If you want to add a new class while retaining the current classes:

```
$("div.ColVis > button").addClass('newButtonClass');
```

The `>` looks for children of the first selector.

Comment: Thanks ! I just need to replace the entire class. Your solution works great ! :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your code won't work merely because you have a typo in the class name "ColVis" (instead of "Colvis"). It's case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

`toggleClass` only affects the class you pass in, in your case it only adds `newButtonClass` - If you want to toggle all the other classes off, include them as an argument:

```
$("div.Colvis button").toggleClass("newButtonClass ColVis_Button ColVis_MasterButton ui-button ui-state-default");
```

If the class is present at the time of this call, it's removed, and if not present, then it's added.

Answer (score 0):

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ssdty/)

**Description**

First I added an event binding so that when the button is clicked something happens.

```
$("div .ColVis button").click(function(e){
```

Next we needed to toggle the `class`:

```
$(this).toggleClass("newButtonClass");
```

Since we are already in an event of the item we are wanting `this` keyword literally means the button element.

**html**

```
<div class="content">
    <form>
        <div id="datagrid">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="ColVis">
                    <button class="ColVis_Button ColVis_MasterButton ui-button ui-state-default">
                        <span>Change Columns</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("div .ColVis button").click(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("newButtonClass");
    //This line is to show it works in the console
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```